# gem list pdfkit for generating excel ruby

Tags: excel, ruby-on-rails-3, pdf-generation, xls

Is there a gem like pdfkit( which converts html to pdf) for converting html table to excel.

Answer (score 4):

You can use either the [to_xls gem](https://github.com/splendeo/to_xls) (which in backend uses spreadsheet) with which you can have an xls file generated when you call (I'm using this in my projects):

```
http://yourpage.com/yourcontroller/youraction.xls
```

Or you can give a try to this plugin:

http://arydjmal.com/2009/1/11/to_xls-plugin-export-to-excel-in-rails-the-easy-way